# WPF application calls an API that needs a message pump; Dispather.Run() causes problems

Tags: wpf, com, message-pump

I have a WPF app that uses a non-WPF vendor library.  My app does not receive any events that the library fires.  I've been told that this is because I need a message pump.

In [another (very similar) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065533/wpf-application-which-calls-an-api-which-needs-a-message-pump), the accepted answer suggested using System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run().

When I add in that call, however, my window won't pop up-- the app is effectively backgrounded and I have to shut it down with Task Manager.

I'm really stumped here, and I'm not even sure how to investigate it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have one if you use WPF, there's no other way that it can get any Windows notifications.  Every WPF app starts life with a call to Application.Run() on the main thread.  It is usually well hidden, auto-generated in the bin\debug\app.g.cs source code file.  Application.Run() in turn calls Dispatcher.Run()

Your vendor is correct, without a message loop many COM components go catatonic.  But since you have one you need to look for the problem elsewhere.  Don't use the component on threads.

Comment: Thanks, then it means I'm not crazy.  I had a demo WPF app that was working, but it doesn't work in my real app.  I thought there might be some aspect of WPF/Dispatcher interaction that I was missing, but it appears not.  My problem must be somewhere else.